# Android: Run app in app in two different views on one screen (splitscreen?)

Tags: android, screen, split

I try to create in an app something like a splitscreen. On the top 50% there should be my own stuff (this shouldn't be the problem). On the other 50% there should run an other app (not mine). It is possible to run launch an other app via intent but is it possible to run an app in an app? Any hints?

Thx
B770

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cornerstone](http://www.onskreen.com/cornerstone/) does that, but I don't know how. I highly doubt it's possible without modifying the firmware.

[Update, Dec 2012] Samsung includes their own version of splitscreen called "multi view" on most high-end smartphones running Jelly Bean. However this isn't open source as Cornerstone seems to be, see their [github page](https://github.com/Onskreen/cornerstone) [/Update]